# Expansion of an ODE near irregular singularity

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider the equation

\begin{equation}
\frac{df}{dt} = \left(\frac{A}{t^2}+\frac{B}{t} \right)f
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a diagonal matrix with distinct eigenvalues.

According to general theory [1,2], there is a solution
\begin{gather}
f(t) = g(t) \exp(-A/t)t^{[B]}
\end{gather}
$[B]$ is the diaginal part of B, and $g$ is a Borel-summable function. It is not possible to represent $g$ as a power series, or as a convergent exponential series near $t=0$.

Question: Is there an explicit representation for $g$?

For specific choice of $A,B$ there is such a form [3].

[1] @article{costin2002formation,
title={On the formation of singularities of solutions of nonlinear differential systems in antistokes directions},
author={Costin, Ovidiu and Costin, RD},
journal={arXiv preprint math/0202234},
year={2002}
}

[2] @book{balser2006divergent,
title={From divergent power series to analytic functions: theory and application of multisummable power series},
author={Balser, Werner},
year={2006},
publisher={Springer}
}

[3] @article{lin2024explicit,
title={Explicit evaluation of the Stokes matrices for certain quantum confluent hypergeometric equations},
author={Lin, Jinghong and Xu, Xiaomeng},
journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:2401.13911},
year={2024}
}